# How can I integrate $\int {dx \over \sqrt{3^2+x^2}} $ using Trigonometric Substitution?

Tags: calculus

$$\int {dx \over \sqrt{9+x^2}} = \int {dx \over \sqrt{3^2+x^2}} $$
$$ x =3\tan\theta$$
$$dx = 3\sec^2\theta$$

$$\int {3\sec^2\theta \over \sqrt{3^2 + 3^2\tan^2\theta}} d\theta$$
$$\int {3\sec^2\theta \over \sqrt{3^2(1+\tan^2\theta)}} d\theta$$
$$\int {3\sec^2\theta \over 3\sec\theta} d\theta = \int \sec\theta$$
$$\ln|\sec\theta + \tan\theta| + C $$
$$\ln\left({\sqrt{9+x^2} \over 3} + {x \over 3}\right)$$

My book says the answer should just be:

$$\ln\left({\sqrt{9+x^2}} + {x}\right) $$

I'm wondering where I went wrong with this?

Comment: To obtain $\sin x$, type \sin x in math mode.  Similarly, type \cos x, \tan x, \sec x, \csc x, \cot x, \ln x, \log x in math mode to obtain $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\sec x$, $\csc x$, $\cot x$, $\ln x$, and $\log x$, respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two results are equivalent, up to choice of constant.

\begin{align}
\ln\left({\sqrt{9+x^2}+x \over 3}\right)+C &= \ln\left(\sqrt{9+x^2} + x\right) - \ln(3) + C \\
&= \ln\left(\sqrt{9+x^2} + x\right) + C'
\end{align}

Comment: Ok I see that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\log (t\times C) = \log t + \log C$$

Answer (score 0):

It should be a printing mistake. Your answer is correct

Comment: As you can see from the other answers, though the OP's answer is correct, so is the book's. There was no printing mistake.